# Printing data from a single dimension of a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

What I want to do is to read/store data in only one dimension of a multidimensional array, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int array [5] [10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Reading %d number in the first dimension.\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &array [i]);/*Trying to store data just on 1st dimension */
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array [i]); /*Trying to print the data read*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Turns out that the program unezpectedly outputs gibberish data:

```
2673556
2673576
2673656
2673566
2673756
```

How do I properly access that single dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 3
#define N 10

int main(void){
    int array [M] [N];
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    for ( ; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Reading %d number in the first dimension.\n", i+1);
        if ( scanf("%d", &array [0][i]) != 1 ) break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%d\n", array[0][j]); /*Tring to print the data read*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 3
#define N 10

int main(void){
    int array [M] [N];
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    for ( ; i < M; i++) {
        printf("Reading %d number in the first dimension.\n", i+1);
        if ( scanf("%d", &array [i][0]) != 1 ) break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%d\n", array[j][0]); /*Tring to print the data read*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first program fills the first row of the array while the second program fills the first column of the array.

Comment: That's what I meant. Now, I'm just a bit curious on some practices on the way you wrote that code.

Why `if ( scanf("%d", &array [i][0]) != 1 ) break;` instead of straight `scanf`.
Also, why initializing `i` before the `for` loop?

I know this is silly, but I'm just curious.

Comment: @Ezequiel Barbosa Function scanf can be unsuccessfull for example when EOF is encountered. So this condotion ( scanf("%d", &array [i][0]) != 1 checks whether a value was read successfully. As for initializing variable i before the loop makes the program more readable. The initialization does not depend on the following loop. So if you for example will remove the loop the program still will be correct.

Answer (score 2):

An 2D array is made by multiple 1D arrays.

If it is an 1D array you access its element  like `a[i]` (the `i`th element), `i` being the index into the array.

Now see 2D array each element is accessed as `a[i][j]`.

Where `i` represents the index into the row (means selecting an 1D array row wise) and then `j` represents the index into that 1D array (like you used to do in 1D arrays).

Answer (score 2):

To access a multi-dimension array for single one, you have to fix a row in your code. The mistake in your code is you have considered your multi dimension array as a single one, rather we need to modify it to a single one like this

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)

scanf("%d",&array[0][i]);
```

Here  `array[0][i]` will generate an array fixed to row 0 and the iteration i will continue as to 10 u will give the input.

similarly with the columns fixed you will need `array[j][0]`and u will end up filling the rows until 5.

if you want to fill both simultaneously than you will have to apply two loops

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
```

`for (j=0;j<10;j++)`

```
scanf("%d",array[i][j]);
```

now this loop first go for 0th row and fill the columns as you give the input until 10.then the 1st row and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`array[dimension][item]` is the way to access items on a single row dimension. You need to two loops: one for going through the row dimensions, and another for the items (column dimension) of each row dimension.

Let's say you filled all of the 5 rows of 10 items:

```
for (dimension = 0; dimension < 5; dimension++)
    for (item = 0; item < 10; item++)
         printf("%d\n", array [dimension][item]);
```

But since you only filled the first row, you don't need another loop.

```
    for (item = 0; item < 10; item++)
         printf("%d\n", array [0][item]);
```

In order to put items on the first row dimension, you need to change `scanf("%d", &array [i]);` to `scanf("%d", &array [0][i]);`

`0` is the index number of the first row dimension, and `i` will be used as the index for each item.

Edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int array [5] [10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Reading %d number in the first dimension.\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &array [0][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    int item;
    // printing the first row dimension
    for (item = 0; item < 10; item++)
         printf("%d\n", array [0][item]);


    return 0;
}
```